# Laravel 5.6 Sending Mail To and Bcc Diffrent subject and template

Tags: laravel-5

I have a problem to make diffrent mail template. When I got email from sender I would like to responce "Thank you" email to him or her. Sametime I would like to get the email details as diffrent type of tempate.

Here is my controller

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{

    public function send(Request $request){

        $data = array(
                        'name'=>$request->name,
                        'email'=>$request->email,
                        'phone'=>$request->phone, 
                        'messagetext'=>$request->message
                    );

  Mail::send('contacttext', $data, function ($message) use ($request){


        $to_email = "myemail@yahoo.co.jp"; // webmaster 
        $to_name  = "webmaster";
        $subject  = "Thank you!";

        $message->subject ($subject);
        $message->from ($request->email, $request->name);
        $message->to ($request->email, $to_name);
        $message->bcc ('webmasteremail@yahoo.co.jp')
        ->from ($request->email, $request->name)
        ->subject ('for web master ');

        if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
            $status = 'error';
        } else {
            $status = 'success';
        }    

        return response()->json(['response' => $status]);

    }

}
```

contacttext.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>Thank you! here is your summary</head>
<body>
<p><strong>name:</strong>   {{ $name }}</p>
<p><strong>email:</strong>  {{ $email }}</p>
<p><strong>message:</strong>        {{ $messagetext }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Email Sender can recive "Thank you" email. Webmaster can recive the email too
but title and subject are overwrite as contacttext template
Could someone teach me what is worng?
I'm thinking it would be great to make as for webmaster template .
I'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: I don't think you can change the subject/from Address on the CC or BCC of an Email. Would it be out of the question to just send a separate email directly to the webmaster?

Comment: @Tim Lewis Thank you for answer. I see I understand. so what is the simple way to separete message for Sender and Webmaster? Could you teach me more? I will poset whole controller

Comment: Duplicate and adjust your `Mail::send()` snippet so it will send only to the Webmaster.

Comment: @Tim Lewis Thanks for quick responce. Actually I did what you said before I post here. it become error and Sender couldn't recive reply. etc ... Could you teach me where to write duplicate the code?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an answer. I'm not sure about putting the `return` inside the `Mail::send()` function, but I'll note that.

Comment: Also, I notice you're sending the email to and from the same email address. Is that intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change attributes of a CC or BCC, as that would invalidate it being a **carbon copy**. If you need to send a copy to an alternative address with a different subject, you will need to send it as a separate email:

```
public function send(Request $request){
    $data = array(
        "name" => $request->name,
        "email" => $request->email,
        "phone" => $request->phone, 
        "messagetext" => $request->message
    );

    Mail::send("contacttext", $data, function ($message) use ($request){
        $message->subject("Thank You!");
        $message->to($request->email);
        $message->from(config("mail")["from"]["address"]);
    }

    Mail::send("contacttext", $data, function ($message){
        $message->subject("For Webmaster");
        $message->to("webmasteremail@yahoo.co.jp");
        $message->from(config("mail")["from"]["address"]);
    }

    return response()->json(["message" => "Email Sent!"], 200);
}
```

Notes: I'm using `config("mail")["from"]["address"]` as the sending address due to the mail being sent from within Laravel. This can be configured from `config/mail.php`

Also, to avoid waiting for the email to send before sending a response to the frontend (origin), move the response() outside of the `Mail::send()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot! I learned so many things Thank you! I appreciate your kindness!